# laravel 5.2 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I am getting this error while creating user.

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()

this is my User.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'role_id'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
}
}
```

my role.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
protected $table = "roles";

protected $fillable = [
    'name','description'
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
}
```

and this is migration I used

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
    });

    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

this is controller code I am using

```
$role = Role::find(1);

    $user = new User();
    $user->name = "Admin";
    $user->email = "email@gmail.com";
    $user->password = bcrypt("password");
    $user->role()->associate($role);
    $user->save();
```

when I run this code I get 
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()"
error

let me know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: try $role = App\Role::find(1); instead of  $role = Role::find(1);

Answer (score 1):

The `associate()` function is used to update a `belongsTo()` relationship. Your `role()` relationship is a `hasOne()`, thats why the method doesn't exist.

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `associate()` method to associate role then change your relationship like below:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
```

replace with

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
```

and

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
```

replace with

```
return $this->hasOne('App\User');
```

Hope this help you well!