# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTrashed()

Tags: php, laravel

Not sure what im doing wrong but im getting this error, and im not sure how to solve it.

i referenced this, but im still unsure, maybe its my schema migration

im using laravel 5.5

[laravel 5.2 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993787/laravel-5-2-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-builderassociat)

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTrashed()

**PostController.php**

```
public function isLikedByMe($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id)->first();
    if (Like::whereUserId(auth()->id())->wherePostId($post->id)->exists()){
        return 'true';
    }
    return 'false';
}

public function like(Post $post)
{
    $existing_like = Like::withTrashed()->wherePostId($post->id)->whereUserId(auth()->id())->first();

    if (is_null($existing_like)) {
        Like::create([
            'post_id' => $post->id,
            'user_id' => auth()->id()
        ]);
    } else {
        if (is_null($existing_like->deleted_at)) {
            $existing_like->delete();
        } else {
            $existing_like->restore();
        }
    }
```

**Likes Model**

```
class Like extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**User model** condensed to whats important

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'likes', 'user_id', 'post_id');
}
```

**Post model**

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'likes');
}
```

**Migration:**

likes migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Posts migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: did you use this in your model  `use SoftDeletes;` ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your Eloquent model should use the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` trait to make use of the `withTrashed()` method.

**Like::class**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Like extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

Comment: i just updated let me know if you think im missing something

Comment: in the meanwhile im going to add that because i didn't have that

Comment: let me try it now

Comment: so the second edit is gets me closer to the objective.

Comment: would you have any idea what the mass assignment is pointing to

Comment: does my migration look accurate

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, the problem was that I used `DB::table($table_name)` instead of calling the model, using the model helped.

Regards